# Enable search function in Pelican-powered blog?

Tags: python, search, blogs, pelican

I'm using Pelican and [Elegant](http://oncrashreboot.com/elegant-best-pelican-theme-features) theme to generate my blog. However, I can't figure out how to turn on the search function. I've added the `tipue_search` and `sitemap` plugins, but no luck. I'm attaching the configuration file `pelicanconf.py` for reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

AUTHOR = u'abc'
SITENAME = u"abc"
DEFAULT_DATE = 'fs'
SITEURL = 'http://example.github.io'
TIMEZONE = 'Asian/Shanghai'
THEME = 'elegant'
DEFAULT_PAGINATION = 10

ARTICLE_URL = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b}/{date:%d}/{slug}/'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b}/{date:%d}/{slug}/index.html'
YEAR_ARCHIVE_SAVE_AS = 'posts/{date:%Y}/index.html'
MONTH_ARCHIVE_SAVE_AS = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b}/index.html'

# Uncomment following line if you want document-relative URLs when developing
# RELATIVE_URLS = True

PLUGIN_PATH = 'pelican-plugins'
PLUGINS = ["sitemap", 
       "tipue_search", 
       "render_math", 
       "summary",
       "neighbors"]

SITEMAP = {
    "format": "xml",
    "priorities": {
        "articles": 0.7,
        "indexes": 0.5,
        "pages": 0.3,
    },
    "changefreqs": {
        "articles": "monthly",
        "indexes": "daily",
        "pages": "monthly",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Tipue search there are some more steps to execute after enabling the plugin. [Here](http://moparx.com/2014/04/adding-search-capabilities-within-your-pelican-powered-site-using-tipue-search/) is a good tutorial.

Don't forget that you can also use [Google Custom Search](https://www.google.com/cse/).

Answer (score 0):

check this link and copy the config file and modified on that
http://blog.john-pfeiffer.com/how-to-set-up-a-pelican-static-blog-site/

Comment: Please include more in your answer than just a link!

Answer (score 0):

Tipue Search is defunct. Use `pelican-algolia` plugin instead from PyPI.

```
pip install pelican-algolia
```

After that define four variable in pelicanconf.py

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID = "<Your Algolia App ID>"
ALGOLIA_SEARCH_API_KEY = "<Your Search-only Api Key>"
ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = "<You Algolia App Index name>"
ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY = <"ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY">
```

A short tutorial on how to configure [Algolia for Pelican](https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/launching-pelican-algolia-plugin-for-pelican).